# Refering to method inside object gives undefined is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I'm just playing around with JavaScript by having a button create a small square which moves downwards indefinitely. However, I ran into a small problem of which I don't understand why.

The code is like so:

```
var parentContainer = document.querySelector('.container'),
    inc = 5;

function Square()
{
    this.pos = 0;
    var thisSquare = null;

    this.create = function()
    {
        var newSquare = document.createElement('div');
        newSquare.className = 'square';
        newSquare.style.top = this.pos + "px";

        thisSquare = parentContainer.appendChild(newSquare);
    }

    this.getSquare = function()
    {
        return thisSquare;
    }

    this.update = function()
    {
        this.pos += inc;
        this.getSquare().style.top = this.pos + "px"; // Ln 26
    }
}


var square = new Square();
square.create();
setInterval(square.update, 100);

console.log(square.getSquare()); // Ln 35
```

The lines marked are where the confusion occurs.

Line 26 and line 35 do in essence the same, calling the `getSquare()` method, however Line 26 fails where Line 35 succeeds.

Line 35 gives me a Node, which is what I want. However, Line 26 gives the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Before I used `var thisSquare = null;`, I used `this.square`. Applying the same logic, I got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting this error? For I am lost.

Comment: `setInterval(square.update.bind(square), 100)`

Comment: `setInterval` is calling the callback as a function, i.e. with the `this` value being the global scope. You'll need to pass a callback that calls it *as a method*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` keyword will be `undefined` inside your nested function (i.e. setInterval function), so you need considering like below to make `this` to refer your object:

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
var square = new Square();
square.create();
setInterval(square.update.bind(square), 100);
```

Comment: Using `square.update.bind(square)` did the trick! I should've known!